# Django: How to create a dropdown from CreateView

Tags: python, django

I have a form that you enter in new clients. Within the client form you should be able to select the branch they are apart of. I have tried to add a select field within the template that lists all the branches as options but it returns nothing. What is the correct way of doing this.

models.py

```
class Client(models.Model):
    branch = models.ForeignKey(Branch)
```

view.py

```
class ClientCreate(CreateView):
   model = Client
   fields = [..., 'branch']
```

form.html

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="."> {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Type</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <select id="id_type" name="type">
        <option value selected="selected">Select</option>
        {% for i in client_create %}
        <option value="{{i.branch}}">{{i.branch}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: did you tried simply writing {% form.as_p %} instead of creating your own dropdown?

Comment: sorry the {% endfor %} is in my code. Corrected the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing it's model not models:

```
class ClientCreate(CreateView):
    model = Client
    fields = [..., 'branch']
```

Second thing, try to use the generated `ModelForm`:

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="."> 
    {% csrf_token %}
    ...
    {{ form.branch }}
</form>
```

Comment: It works if i do it like that but i wanted more control over the form template

Comment: you can use `{{ form.branch }}` it will result the select with all options

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I was after. Thank you. If you want to update your answer I will mark it as answered